# Datasnap\FireDAC: Query executed twice

Tags: delphi, firebird, datasnap, firedac

I have the following problem:

1) I use Delphi XE7 to develop a 3-layer system.

2) The server layer, created with datasnap using REST.

3) I use Firebird as database and the access is performed with FireDAC.

4) I have a sequence with value **01**.

5) I created the following query in the server layer:

> **Select GEN_ID (gen_my_sequence, 1) from rdb $ database**

6) On the server returns the sequence value in the query is: **02**.

7) But the client layer returns 03.

I do not understand why the query is executed twice.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How exactly run the query( procedure to get generator value) on the server side and the client side?

Comment: @ValMarinov, please see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use technical standards that the Embarcadero indicates.

What I realized was this:

1) The unit **Data.FireDACJSONReflect** in **TFDJSONInterceptor.ItemListToJSONObject** routine has this block of code:

```
if not LActive then
   LDataSet.Active := True;
try
   LJSONDataSet := DataSetToJSONValue(LDataSet);
   // Use AddPair overload that will accept blank key
   AJSONObject.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create(LPair.Key, LJSONDataSet))
finally
   if not LActive then
      LDataSet.Active := False;
 end;
```

See he activates the query once, causing the sequence to be incremented.

But in **DataSetToJSONValue (LDataSet)** routine; This code block is:

```
if  (LMemTable = nil) then
    begin
    LMemTable := TFDMemTable.Create(nil);
    LAdapter := TFDTableAdapter.Create(nil);
    LMemTable.Adapter := LAdapter;
    LAdapter.SelectCommand := ADataSet.Command;
    LMemTable.Active := True;
    end;
```

See he again activates the query, where the sequence is again incremented.

Now I do not know if I made a mistake or if it is a bug, but I created a new class inherited from **TFDMemTable** and thought there was some mistake in this class, but did a test with **TFDMemTable** component, standard component of FireDAC, and even then the activation of any query is performed twice, because the code does not consider any of these two classes, as a **TFDCustomMemTable**, even though they were inherited directly from this class.

I commented the code of **DataSetToString routine (const ADataSet: TFDAdaptedDataSet)** that looked like this:

```
LMemTable   := nil;
LAdapter    := nil;
try
    //if  (ADataSet is TFDCustomMemTable) then
  LMemTable := TFDCustomMemTable(ADataSet);

  {if  (LMemTable = nil) then
      begin
      LMemTable := TFDMemTable.Create(nil);
      LAdapter := TFDTableAdapter.Create(nil);
      LMemTable.Adapter := LAdapter;
      LAdapter.SelectCommand := ADataSet.Command;
      LMemTable.Active := True;
      end;}
```

In this way the problem was solved, and the performance of the application seemed to have improved.

Comment: Yes. Find this line `LMemTable.Active := True; // query is executed 2nd time!` here : http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=126914

Comment: So it's a Bug! I'm relieved!
Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

This is the nature of generators (sequences) in firebird. Their value is increased every time you request it and the value of the generator is updated from that request and remains updated. Also generators live outside of transaction control.
See this [firebirdsql generatorguide-basics](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/generatorguide-basics.html). It doesn't matter where you request it from.

Comment: Thank you for feedback.

But my question is about DataSnap because the value of the sequence is changed while reading the client layer.

At the same time do the query request in the client layer, the server returns a value, but the value in the client layer is again incremented.

The Firebird is doing right, the return value to the client layer is being different.

The strange thing is that the log of the server layer, is performed only one request.

Comment: Is it possible that you code (the server layer maybe) increases it? Outside of the firebird context.

Comment: You gave a good idea, but i checked it out and there is no routine self-increment the sequence.

The sequence of the Firebird itself is increased, and the Delphi has not how to know which sequence I'm using before I tell it to him.

It's very strange ... in the client layer request routine, the value already comes duplicated the layer server, but the server log shows that was increased only once ...

Comment: @Luiz **Each** time that query is executed, the generator gets increased. So if you execute that query from your app and from ISQL, it gets increased twice. If the component 'refreshes', it gets increased again. And so on.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but in ISQL i used: Select gen_id(gen_my_sequence, 0) from rdb$database.