# Delphi Datasnap Server MySQL FOUND_ROWS() return 1

Tags: mysql, delphi, datasnap

I have a Delphi XE8 Datasnap server with a `GetProduct` method returning two `TFDQuery` in a `TFDJSONDataSets`

```
function TServerMethods1.GetProduct: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  // Clear active so that query will reexecute.
  FDQueryResult.Active    := False;
  FDQueryFoundRows.Active := False;

  Result := TFDJSONDataSets.Create;

  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, 'result',    FDQueryResult); 
  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, 'foundRows', FDQueryFoundRows);
end;
```

`FDQueryResult.SQL.Text` is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM products LIMIT 0,100
```

`FDQueryFoundRows.SQL.Text` is:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS FoundRows
```

**the problem**

`FDQueryFoundRows` always return `1`, but the same query on MySQL Workbrench return the correct number.

I think `FDQueryResult` after execution close the connection and `FDQueryFoundRows` reopen it, but `FOUND_ROWS()` work only on same connection.

how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using the commands in the same `FDTransaction`?

Comment: @jean jung I don't know... how see it?

Comment: See topic QT: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/TFDQuery,_TFDStoredProc_and_TFDUpdateSQL_Questions

Comment: Sorry for the typo, topic Q7

Comment: I found the problem!

solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30758467/3043248